# form is getting submitted with unbind

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       //$('#student').change(function() { 
      $('#but').click(function() { 
      var payid = $("#feType").val();
      var course = $("#course").val();
      var course_id = $("#course_id").val();
      var stud_id = $("#student").val();
      var paid_amt1 = $("#paid_amt").val();

      var serializedData = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: '<?php echo ADMINPATH;?>student/getNewFee/'+payid+'/'+course_id+'/'+stud_id+'/'+course,
                data: '',
                async: true,                    
                success: function(data){

                  if(data == false){
                     $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                     alert("This student doesn't have transport");
                     return false;
                  }
                  var result = data; 

                  if(Number(result) >= Number(paid_amt1)){
                    $("#fee_data").submit(function(){
                      return true;
                    });    
                  }else {
                    $("form").unbind('submit');
                      alert("Due Amount is less than paid amount");
                      return false;        
                  }
               }      
         });

    });

</script>
```

If the data is coming to if condition the form has to submit, and if data is coming to else condition form submitting should stop. "if" condition is working well, but coming to else the form is still getting submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line, it is not needed and you are triggering the submit with it:

```
$("form").unbind('submit').submit();
```

If you only want to remove the on submit callback, you can do this:

```
$("form").unbind('submit');
```

You need to add a `return false` before the end of the click event:

```
$('#but').click(function() { 
  // ....
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Please post all the code of your JavaScript.  Put this above your `if` condition `console.log(Number(result) >= Number(paid_amt1))` -- what does it show in your console?

Comment: It sounds like it is not even triggering the alert

Comment: Ah, okay, please post more of your code by editing your question.  It sounds like something else may be wrong.

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal2" id="fee_data" name="fee_data" action="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>student/feepaymentedit" method='post' >

Comment: <button  name="submit" value="Submit" id="but" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

Comment: you need to add return false, check my post

Answer (score 0):

You are calling submit() method from else portion. 
Remove below code from else portion.

```
 $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
```

Comment: yes I've done removing that line, still the form is submitting

Comment: May be you mentioned submit button in form. Don't give button type "submit".

Comment: yes I removed button type "submit". and I kept input type="submit"/ input type="button" noting worked

Comment: You need to call function on click of that button. Use Onclick event. or  in script tag  put $("#addOffer").click(function(){});

Comment: sry but here I am using button for different functions, so I could not write onclick

Comment: You need to find a way. Check button text or any other property in javascript  then call that function. If you are satisfy with my answer upvote my answer.

Comment: I've posted the complete script